# Do we have a sanbox for HERE Map Feedback API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

Am I right that for developers' purposes: testing and actual development we just need to use credentials posted here https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/map_feedback/place-details-feedback?
E.g we do not have any special endpoint AKA sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

There is no sandbox or CIT environment for the HERE Map Feedback API available that is correct.
The credentials which you see in the example page are not for external usage nor development purpose. Please use your own credentails for acessing the service.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. Is that okay then to spam requests to that endpoint during the development stage? I don't want you guys to register those test requests as real ones. Any workaround?